# How to flush the Windows Event Log to disk?

Tags: c++, windows, events, logging

I have a Windows 7 embedded device which is frequently power cycled like this:  a local application writes an entry to the Application event log and a few seconds later it commands the custom power supply to cycle power.  A clean Windows shutdown cannot be done.  After the device boots back up, I check the Windows event log and notice the last entry missing.

Is there some way to flush the Windows event log to disk so that I don't miss that last entry?  The application is written in C++.

Thanks,
Adnan

Comment: Why do you think it matters? What *actual* problem are you trying to solve? The OS itself takes care of this and ensures the events are always preserved **assuming** you used the correct functions. Post your code

Comment: BTW if your application causes an abnormal shutdown, you should fix the application. It's not just your event message that can be lost - you'll also lose data, could cause corruption of unsaved or half-saved files.

Comment: The "actual" problem is hardware related.  The system contains custom boards which are malfunctioning and require power cycling to resolve.  The proper solution is to fix the hardware, but this is beyond my scope.  The same power supply also powers the Windows embedded SBC.  The Windows ReportEvent api function is used to write to the event log and a COM port message is sent to the power supply to tell it to cycle power.

Comment: Why don't you perform a restart instead with [InitiateSystemShutdownEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376874(v=vs.85).aspx)? That API allows you to specify a reason *and* allow the OS to properly shutdown.

Comment: That's a good idea.  But the Windows system needs to continue to run in the event that the power supply does not receive the COM port command to cycle power.  As a backup, the application waits a few minutes and just does an orderly reboot using ExitWindowsEx, but that does not solve the hardware related issue and so it tries to power cycle again.

Answer (score 1):

You have a hardware problem so the best solution is to resolve it in hardware. But moving on.

**Use BIOS to ensure computer always starts after a power cycle**

You have a hardware tool to perform the reboot. Could you reconfigure that so that rather than doing a hard power cycle while the computer is running, you:

- notify the hardware power cycle tool,
- perform an orderly shutdown, then
- power the computer on again using the hardware power switch?

There is usually a bios setting which allows you to specify the action after a power cycle, e.g.

- Leave the computer off,
- Turn it on,
- Turn it on only if it was on when power was lost.

If you can do this, then you can still do an orderly shutdown and wait for that to complete before powering on again.

**Software Solution: Turn off disk write caching**

It's not exactly clear what is causing your issue, but the following seem relevant.

Most likely, this is a result of disk write caching either by the disc controller hardware, or by the operating system.

You may be able to turn this off through the Disk Management tool:

- http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-disable-disk-write-caching-windows-7-8

**Software Solution: Flush the disk programmatically**

Alternatively, you may be able to flush the disk cache programmatically. This tool may help:

- https://superuser.com/questions/833552/manually-flushing-write-cache-on-window

Or indeed with WMI and PowerShell:

- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn454975.aspx

Comment: Ben, thanks for the good suggestions.  I tried manually flushing the disk cache using SysInternals' sync utility as you suggested, but no success.  I will try disabling the disk write cache, but I'm not sure that would be a good solution in the long run for performance.

Comment: It would certainly not be good for performance, you are right there. But these are not good solutions. If you have a good solution you should use that instead :-) If not I hope these help.